# Reoccurring serial elements are not part of the RSS-Feed

Tags: sharepoint-server, rss

I have problems correctly integrating our SharePoint RSS-Feed.

With Serial elements it seems as if only the first date of the element is part of the RSS-Feed as one long event and not separated in single events.

**The calendar/list has two example entries. A single entry and a serial element:**
[image: Calendar]

**The RSS-Feed only shows the single element and the first element of the series. The serial elements seems to be 4 days long, because its start date is 01.09.2020 17:00 to 04.09.2020 18:00:**

[image: RSS-Feed]

**The RSS-Settings are set to show items within 31 days and a maximum of 100 entries. I don't see anything else inside the settings which has to do with this:**
[image: RSS-Settings]

Is our SharePoint-Version just buggy and needs an update to fix it or does anyone know how so solve this?

Comment: I don't see a problem here, the calendar is as per the rss feed.

Comment: The problem ist that the reoccurring event is listed as one long event which takes 4 days instead of 4 separate events. 

Another example: A reoccurring event wich only happens once a month for example wouldn’t be listed in this rss-feed if I set the settings to load only the last 31 days.